# Check if www page is in text android

Tags: android, regex

I want to check if www page is in text. For example i have page address: www.taktik.com/trow and want check if text for www is in text.
I use  `Matcher mW = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(question);` but I don't get any results. How can I check if text xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxx is in my String?

Comment: are you trying to check for the presence of a specific URL? or just determine whether any URL at all is contained within your String?

Comment: whetever any url, not specific

Comment: [This](http://rubular.com/) is a helpful tool. I just put in your current regex and it doesnt match the pattern you provided.

Comment: Thx @Naveed. This site helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if text xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxx is in my String?

Fixing your regex, the pattern may look like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+
```

Mind I escaped thr first dot and placed the hyphen at the end of the last two character classes (in yours, you have `9-.` that creates a range that matches more than you'd want).

I tried to shorten the pattern a bit, but it's difficult since \w also matches Unicode characters in Android. Here is a possible regex:

```
(?i)[A-Z0-9_+-]+(?:\\.[A-Z0-9-]+){2}/[A-Z0-9-]+
```